# c++ untyped value object/variable library with defined operation overloads

Tags: c++, json, overloading, operation, non-type

I don't know exactly how to define what I am searching, but, here I go:
Since the library libjsoncpp exists and lets us hold a value in an object that is "json based", which means, an integer, an unsigned number, double, string or null... (also arrays and objects that can be seen -or I perceive- as pointer based objects to other objects),

... is there any kind of library in which we could operate with those data, more or less as we do in javascript?

```
#include "somemagiclib.h"

magicnamespace::jsonlike_o value1=10;
int integervalue=15;
magicnamespace::jsonlike_o value2="hello_world";
std::string anything="anything";
magicnamespace::jsonlike_o value3="10.3";
magicnamespace::jsonlike_b result;

value3=value2+value1;
std::cout << "value3 is: " << value3.asString() << std::endl;
   /*value3 is: 21*/
std::cout << (value2+value1).asString() << std::endl;
   /*hello_world10*/
std::cout << (value1+value3).asString() << std::endl;
   /*20*/
std::cout << (value3+value1).asString() << std::endl;
   /*10.310*/
std::cout << (value1<value3).asString() << std::endl;
   /*true*/
std::cout << (value1+integervalue).asString() << std::endl;
   /*25*/
std::cout << (value1+anything).asString() << std::endl;
   /*18*/
std::cout << (value1>=integervalue).asString() << std::endl;
   /*false*/
std::cout << (value2+integervalue).asString() << std::endl;
   /*hello_world15*/
std::cout << (value2+anything).asString() << std::endl;
   /*hello_worldanything*/
```

We could easily reach to the ask "what for?" (...or even "wtf for?"). In fact, I am working on a project that requires a part of json processing to compare values that are obtained from part based ports transmitting in serial protocols, compared with values that are obtained from json based configured files.

Being able to code or preview the future scenarios is becoming difficult, since we also have to preview incoming values from JsonRPC based objects, so the code may become expensive to generate or to maintain.

Do you know if there's any kind of library that implements this kind of "non-typed" type in C++?
 In case of not knowing, do you think that this kind of library deserves the efforts to be created?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: If you want to write in javascript then what is the point for you to switch to C++ trying to ignore its modestly strong type system?

Comment: In fact we are already working in C++. The point is not to write in javascript, but to be able to serialize objects to json. We are growing from a very low level layer with the prevision of the integration of libraries written in C and C++, and a real time approach is necessary.
Of course, we would love that all the libraries we are using to calculate values of UART packets were already implemented... and with wrappers in CPython, or javascript... but it is not the case.
It becomes not acceptable to loose responsivity in the serial packets processing, while json processing is not critical.

Comment: While we are investigating... it would be awsome if we could even have some kind of object to _evaluate_ the content of the object, optimized for c. In other case, we think that we should create some kind of similar object to save code, in prevision for the maintanence.
We cannot just simply work in **javascript**. It's very _expensive_ for the processor.

Answer (score 1):

Look into crow c++. its not just json stuff, its pretty much flask for c++. might be useful. it's also just a header file, so no installation etc is needed